# How do I get sorted dates using union on multiple select statements?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, union

```
SELECT ITEM, TXNDate, RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),PREVDATE,6),7),  RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(year,1,NEXTVDATE),6),7) FROM TABLE
```

this retrieves as below

```
-------------------------------------------
ITEM    | TXNDate  |PREVDATE  |  NEXTDATE |
-------------------------------------------
item-A    03 Jan 13    Jan 13    Jan 14 
item-C    06 Jan 13    Jan 13    Jan 14 
item-B    08 Jan 13    Jan 13    Jan 14 
item-A    05 Feb 13    Feb 13    Feb 14 
item-B    07 Feb 13    Feb 13    Feb 14 
item-B    16 Mar 13    Mar 13    Mar 14 
item-A    03 Apr 13    Apr 13    Apr 14 
_______________________________________
```

Here I'm trying to show dates in Ordered manner

```
SELECT * INTO #DATES FROM (SELECT PREVDATE  DATES  from #DATA  
               UNION
                   SELECT NEXTDATE DATES from #DATA) p
SELECT * FROM #DATES
```

But I'm getting this result

```
----------
|  DATES |
----------
 Apr 13
 Apr 14
 Feb 13
 Feb 14
 Jan 13
 Jan 14
 Mar 13
 Mar 14
---------
```

Please help me to get result as

```
----------
|  DATES |
----------
 Jan 13
 Jan 14 
 Feb 13
 Feb 14
 Mar 13
 Mar 14
 Apr 13
 Apr 14
---------
```

Comment: ,guess you are trying to order varchar,hence the problem.no need of insert and temp table just to order.Most importantly why change date format.In DB always keep date data as datetime/date only.you can change the format while displaying.Also there are three column of date.you want to sort which one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add `ORDER BY` to your last `SELECT` to get the dates in an ascending order:

```
SELECT * INTO #DATES FROM (SELECT PREVDATE  DATES  from #DATA  
               UNION
                   SELECT NEXTDATE DATES from #DATA) p
SELECT * FROM #DATES
ORDER BY DATEPART(MONTH, CONVERT(DATE, '01 ' + DATES)), 
    DATEPART(YEAR, CONVERT(DATE, '01 ' + DATES))
```

As your dates are strings, you need to convert them to dates. Then get the month and year parts as this is the order you want.

Comment: Thanks Nicky... I already have tried same solution suggested by you.. but the dates i'm selecting are varchar type values

Comment: @RupeshS Also, only now noticed that you want the order by month first then by year. Updated the answer.

Comment: @Nikhy, Hey Man!!! Ur really Great.. Thanks a lot... i got the result that i want...

Comment: This is actually Szymon. NickyvV is the person who provided the other answer :) I'm glad it works.

Comment: thanks to both u... help one, each one... makes our lives easy

Answer (score 0):

The ordering you want in your result is a little strange, because you want `Jan 14` to be before `Feb 13`?

Without an `ORDER BY` clause you will never be certain of the way the records are ordered. Including this clause is therefore necessary, as explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by.aspx)

```
SELECT * INTO #DATES FROM 
  (SELECT PREVDATE  DATES  from #DATA  
     UNION
   SELECT NEXTDATE DATES from #DATA
  ) p

SELECT *
FROM #DATES
ORDER BY DATES
```